# Отправка данных через сокет (упаковка) с++

Tags: c++, linux, сокет, tcp, udp

Необходимо отправить данные типа:float/int/char через сокет, как организовать "упаковку" на стороне отправителя что бы отправить всё одним пакетом, и "распаковать" на принимающей стороне.

В сети нашёл скрин приложения для игры, как упаковать так же?

[image]

Comment: можно упаковать в бинарный формат и распаковать на стороне клиента, ну а что бы отправлять структуры данных, то скорее вам нужно упаковывать структуру

Answer (score 5):

Примитивный способ для простых случаев - описать структуру данных:

```
struct Data {
    int a;
    float b;
    char c[32];
} data;
```

Записать её в сокет на передающей стороне (`send(socket, &data, sizeof(data), 0)` и на принимающей прочитать в точно такую же структуру (`recv(socket, &data, sizeof(data), 0)`). **Очень важно** чтобы стуктура на обоих сторонах (передающей и приемной) была идентичной по расположению в памяти (одинаковые размеры типов, одинаковый порядок байтов в системе, одинаковое выравнивание полей структуры, одинаковое представление чисел с плавающей точкой). Иначе получаем не те данные, что отправили. На практике, если принимающая сторона ещё и на другом языке написана, получим лишнюю возню и простор для появления ошибок.

---

Следующий вариант - набивать буфер данных вручную:

```
int foo = 42;
long bar = 0;
std::string str;
str.append((char*)&foo, sizeof(int));
str.append((char*)&bar, sizeof(long));
```

Здесь уже нет проблемы с выравниванием полей структуры как в первом варианте, т.к. данные мы склеиваем сами, без промежутков. Но остальные проблемы пока ещё с нами (по прежнему порядок байтов, размеры типов, представление чисел с плавающей точкой должны быть идентичными на передатчике и приемнике).

---

Ручная, побайтовая набивка потока.

```
uint32_t foo = 42;
std::vector<uint8_t> buffer;
buffer.push_back(static_cast<uint8_t>(foo >> 0));
buffer.push_back(static_cast<uint8_t>(foo >> 8));
buffer.push_back(static_cast<uint8_t>(foo >> 16));
buffer.push_back(static_cast<uint8_t>(foo >> 24));
```

Здесь просто берем каждый кусок данных и вручную переносим в выходной поток в независимом от системы порядке. Разбирать тоже придется вручную. Наиболее универсальный способ, т.к. все аспекты генерируемого потока контролируем сами. Для удобства можно написать класс сериализатора/десериализатора для требуемых типов (включая пользовательские).

---

Со временем (а может быть и сразу) добавляются сложности, связанные с изменением передаваемых данных (например понадобилось передать дополнительные данные или какие-то старые уже стали неактуальными). Особенно если приемник должен принимать данные и в старом формате и в новом. Придется добавлять какие-то идентификаторы версии.
Дополнительно нужно обработать случаи, когда нужно передать опциональные данные (которые могут отсутствовать) или данные динамического размера (массивы).

---

Чтобы не решать все эти задачи самостоятельно, можно взять готовое решение, например [protobuf](https://github.com/google/protobuf) от google. Поддерживает разные языки, имеет систему версий, поддержку комплексных данных. 
Или немного более простое решение (но и более быстрое), тоже от google [flatbuffers](https://google.github.io/flatbuffers/).

---

Если объем передаваемой информации не критичен, возможно будет удобным формировать данные в виде json (например с помощью https://github.com/nlohmann/json). Если на принимающей стороне JavaScript программист, он будет вам очень благодарен (да и не только JavaScript программист).
Также, как программисту из типизированного языка, рекомендую использовать [схемы](http://json-schema.org) для проверки json.

Как альтернативу json можно взять [messagepack](http://msgpack.org/index.html), который "как json", но компактнее. Если нужно ещё компактнее, можно пожать передаваемую строку с помощью zlib например.

---

Для всех вариантов также надо учитывать, что передавать **указатели** бессмысленно, т.к. на принимающей стороне они будут указывать неизвестно куда. Также понимать тонкости передачи данных по сети. К примеру данные, отправленные по UDP, могут не дойти до получателя, данные отправленные по TCP могут быть фрагментированы или склеены с соседними при получении и т.п. Возможно стоит подумать о готовых сетевых библиотеках, например [RakNet](https://github.com/OculusVR/RakNet), которая включает в себя практически все для построения мультиплеерной игры.

Comment: Откуда проблема с размерами во втором варианте? Там еще str на buffer надо заменить.

Comment: Спасибо за зоркий взгляд! ) Про размеры - в том плане, что на другой стороне `int` например 8-ми байтовый. Поправил, чтобы было понятнее.

Comment: Спасибо! Очень заинтересовала "побитовая набивка"!

Answer (score 3):

В функциях отправки данных на другой сокет (например, send) и функциях приема данных (например, recv) одним из параметров всегда является указатель на буфер с этими данными (байтами). Необходимо предварительно сформировать этот буфер. Сделать это можно очень разными способами. Например, если структура передаваемых данных динамическая и/или таких структур очень много, то можно формировать буфер, так сказать, "на лету". Т.е. мы нужные данные постепенно, по мере их получения, запихиваем в буфер.

```
    std::string buffer;
    uint32_t i32 = 0x32fe56ad;
    float f = 1.0;
    std::string str = "1234";
    uint8_t sz = str.size();
    buffer.append((char*)&i32, sizeof(i32));
    buffer.append((char*)&f, sizeof(f));
    buffer.append((char*)&sz, sizeof(sz));
    buffer.append(str);

    std::cout << "lenght message: " <<buffer.size() << " bytes" << std::endl;
    std::cout << " message: ";

    for(size_t i=0; i<buffer.size(); i++)
        printf("%x ",(uint8_t)buffer[i]);
```

Для простоты, в примере, в качестве буфера я использовал строку. Но лучше будет написать какой-то свой класс, со своими методами с использованием шаблонов для разных типов пакуемых данных. Обратите внимание, что перед тем, как передать строку (внутри буфера), упаковывается ее размер. Когда с другой стороны на приеме Вы будете доставать строку, то предварительно уже будете знать ее длину и сколько байт из буфера читать для получения строки. В данном случае я паковал размер в один байт. Но в идеале лучше паковать [VLQ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_quantity). Само собой, при разборе данных на другой стороне Вы должны извлекать их в переменные с такими же типами/размерами и в таком же порядке, как и упаковывали.

Если данные передаются постоянные и однотипные, то можно использовать в качестве указателя на буфер с данными непосредственно структуру. Но лучше всего, наверное, ее использовать для упаковки тривиальных типов.

```
    struct pack
    {
        uint32_t i32 = 0x32fe56ad;
        float f = 1.0;
        unsigned char str[5] = "1234";
    };

    pack pax;
    uint8_t *p = (uint8_t*)&pax;
    std::cout << "lenght message: " <<sizeof(pax) << " bytes" << std::endl;
    std::cout << " message: ";
    for(size_t i=0; i<sizeof(pax); i++)
    {
        printf("%x ",*p);
        p++;
    }
```

Структурированные данные проще принять и распаковать на другой стороне. Но есть в целом несколько ньюансов, которые необходимо учитывать. Так, например, если в структуре будут указатели на другие типы данных, то передать эти данные так просто не получится. Также размер структуры может быть выровнен и фактически будет больше, чем количество данных.

И еще хотелось бы заметить... Не путайте отправляемые данные непосредственно с пакетом уходящим в сеть. Те данные (буфер, сообщение), которое Вы упакуете и отправите будет по факту разбито на несколько пакетов. Эти пакеты (части Ваших данных) придут на другой конец в произвольном порядке в случае использования UDP и по порядку - при TCP (но все равно кусками). Поэтому, к отправляемым данным, еще желательно впереди упаковать что-то типа заголовка (header), в котором будет содержаться длина всего Вашего сообщения (а для UDP еще и порядковый номер сообщения).

*P.S: код в ответе приведен исключительно для понимания процесса, но никак не для оценки его функциональности и корректности.*

Comment: Замечание по отправке через `UDP` сокет - если вы отправляете кусок данных одной командой (send/write), то, не смотря на возможную фрагментацию на уровне `IP`, приемная сторона получает его целиком (на уровне сокетов) или не получает вообще. Другое дело, что две отправки через `send` могут быть получены в любом порядке.

Comment: Наверное стоит добавить ещё, что пример упаковки не учитывает порядок расположения байтов в памяти.

Comment: @sergw а мне то Вы зачем это написали.. У меня есть своя реализация сериализцации. Прочитайте справку и напишите это топикастеру.

Answer (score 2):

Правильным подходом будет использование [сериализации](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F) данных.
Например: [Protocol Buffers](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protocol_Buffers), [JSON](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON), [XML](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML), [ASN.1](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASN.1), и т.п. [Сравнительная таблица](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_data_serialization_formats).